# No game achievements in steam at all

Tags: macos, games, steam

Buy the game Monochroma some time ago and no one achievement has earned until I passed it. Already trying to get help in steam forum, but nothing. Maybe anyone have this kind of problem on mac platform with steam games? Thanks for watching!

Comment: How is that a Mac problem?, what Mac do you have?

Comment: Yeah, only in my MBP latest 2013.

Comment: Any more variants?

Answer (score 2):

Steam uses OS X's Accessibility API for the Steam Overlay (Shift+Tab screen) and to communicate between the game and Steam.app. You probably enabled it when you installed Steam. Unfortunately, every time you update Steam (this is a bug in OS X) you must uncheck and re-check the box in System Preferences. If you're having this issue on your Mac but not Windows, that's the reason.

Just go to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**, unlock using the icon in the bottom left, and uncheck and re-check Steam.

Comment: Thanks, but not helping for me. Trying it for many times - but no changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try:

1. Make sure all your OSX updates are installed
2. Follow 0942v8653's suggestion and toggle off the Accessibility API for steam
3. Completely remove Steam
4. Reboot
5. Reinstall Steam
6. Toggle back on the Accessibility API
7. Reboot

There may well be better ways, but this is my hip-shot guess on this one.

Comment: Unfortunately, not help too. I think it's a game issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give Steam access in the accessibility settings and then you may need to restart Steam and or reinstall. I have had a similar issue where Steam does not detect that it has been given permission in the settings and it was fixed by a quick reinstallation of Steam.

Comment: Already try this kind of variant - not help. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Weird! Whenever I have had this issue that has worked. Wait, that was on Mavericks! Let me try now!

Comment: Now, I am experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: As i said above, I think it's all about this game - "Monochroma", other games achievements work fine.

Comment: Weird, I experienced it on other games to.

Comment: "Work fine" for games in my list of course.

Comment: Yeah, I think it may have something to do with the type of game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19807/discussion-between-benjamin-and-kirbrown).